# Cannot declare class HunterObfuscator, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, laravel

I never used PHP before but I am trying to check on of the libraries in a PHP project.
Lets say I have an `test/License.php` file and I want to use a library called HunterObfuscator [link](https://github.com/nicolauns/hunter-php-javascript-obfuscator).

According to the documentation I copy the HunterObfuscator.php file and paste in the same directory like `test/HunterObfuscator.php`.

Then inside the `License.php` I use the library like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'HunterObfuscator.php';
class LicenseController extends Controller {
  public function licenseControl(Request $req) {
    $jsCode = "alert('Hello world!');"; //Simple JS code
    $hunter = new HunterObfuscator($jsCode); //Initialize with JS code in parameter
    $obsfucated = $hunter - > Obfuscate(); //Do obfuscate and get the obfuscated code

  }

}
```

After running I get the following error:

> ```
> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
> Cannot declare class HunterObfuscator, because the name is already in use
> ```

Comment: And what is you remove the require ? seems already included.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Does HunterObfuscator already loaded by the autoloader ? Try to comment the line `require_once 'HunterObfuscator.php';`.

Comment: Not loaded.  It return error if not called